# Entity Framework: Run EF Migrations for Previous Version in Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I have Net Core 3.1.1000 installed.
Now we are trying to run ef migrations with EF Core 2.2.6 database previous Solution,

when running the following, receive error below.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

> The application to execute does not exist: .dotnet\tools.store\dotnet-ef\2.2.6-servicing-10079\dotnet-ef\2.2.6-servicing-10079\tools\netcoreapp2.2\any\dotnet-ef.dll'.

How can we resolve this?

How Can I point directly to the DLL target directory and execute? I heard renaming file directory is not good idea.

I see the real dll is located here:

> ....dotnet\tools.store\dotnet-ef\2.2.6\dotnet-ef\2.2.6\tools\netcoreapp2.2\any\dotnet-ef.dll

already ran this and installed this: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

Comment: hi @TheGeneral read that, not sure what was the proposed solution, they have a slightly different issue I believe

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#dotnet-ef ?

Comment: completely remove previous version of .net core and try again. and change your target platform version of .net core in project properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

To fix it, you should follow these two steps.

1. Install EF tool as a local or global tool. Open your terminal and run: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`.

   > From .NET Core v3, the EF tool is no longer part of the .NET Core SDK.
   >
   > Github issue [#14016](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14016#issuecomment-488030233) /
   > Microsoft [Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#dotnet-ef)
2. Install the previous .NET Core SDK. [.NET Core v2.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/sdk-2.2.401-windows-x64-installer)

**To Reproduce This Error**

I created a clean virtual machine and I just installed .NET Core v3. Then, I ran the command `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` as you mentioned. I got the following error: [image]

So I installed the previous .NET Core SDK version (v2.2) and the problem was solved.

**Recommendation**

[Microsoft does not recommend using .NET Core version 2.x.x](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2). These releases have reached the end of life, meaning it is no longer supported. They recommend moving to a supported release, such as .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1, based on your updates I've simulated your error and I could find the proper solution. Also, I've changed a little bit my answer to help you out. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

How about running the below command in Visual Studio's Package Manager Console.

```
add-migration InitialCreate
```